# Find the next blank column on specific ROW with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need some help I need to find the next blank column on specific row because my table has some headers and blank spaces on the bottom i try a lot of methods and doesn't work for me

I need to find the next blank column on the row number 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sheet3.Cells(4, Sheet3.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)
```

specifies the first blank cell in row 4 of Sheet3.

Comment: for completeness I added sheet reference to `Column`

Comment: User3598756: Sheet3.Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft) works perfectly on my computer: Excel 2010

Comment: @Variatus, I prefaced _"for completeness"_ since a "bare" `Columns` would reference the _Active_ sheet which can be different than `Sheet3`. Yet it'd not cause an error unless 1) `Sheet3` were not a `CodeName`, thus implicitly belonging to the _Active_ workbook 2) `Sheet3` were not in the _Active_ workbook 2) the _Active_ workbook and `Sheet3` parent workbook were from different Excel version supporting different maximum numbers of columns. Just _"for completeness"_ ...

Comment: Um, you need to tack on an .offset(0,1) to target the 1st blank column.  Also a check should take place to make sure prior to the "offset()" , that you are not in column 1. Finally, not sure when Ram added Column "5" but perhaps your example should reflect that.